# Tag list using attributed string only

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to mimic the screenshot below using `NSAttributedString` instead of a full-fledged `UICollectionView`.

[image]

I'm almost there but I can't get the white line spacing and line breaks right:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
let attributedText = myList.reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString()) { result, next in
    let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "   ")
    text.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: next))
    text.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "   "))
    text.addAttributes(
        [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGrey,
            .backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
        ],
        range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)
    )

    result.append(text)

    guard myList.last != next else { return }
    result.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "  "))
}

attributedText.addAttributes(
    [
        .paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle().with {
            $0.alignment = .center
            $0.lineHeightMultiple = 2
            $0.lineSpacing = 12
        }
    ],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)
)

attributedText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n"))

myLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Are there attributes that can handle this to make it look like the first screenshot?

Comment: Floowing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939025/nsattributedstring-highlight-background-color-shows-between-lines-ugly + this simple code where you might want to get some ideas https://github.com/facebookarchive/AsyncDisplayKit/pull/3008 might help you

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer with a quick manual fix at "Meal " position. You may not need it depends on your label layout.

```
let attributedText = myList.reduce(into: NSMutableAttributedString()) { result, next in



        let whitespace = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "   ")
        whitespace.addAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray,
                .backgroundColor: UIColor.white
            ],
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: whitespace.length)
        )


        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string:  next)

        text.addAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray,
                .backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
            ],
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)
        )


        result.append(whitespace)
        if(next.hasPrefix("Meal")){
             result.append(whitespace)

        }
        result.append(text)
           result.append(whitespace)
        guard myList.last != next else { return }
        result.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "  "))
    }
```

[image]